# A noun for a country you live in and that's not your home country

Tags: word-request

Suppose you are from country X, and had to travel to and live in a foreign country Y for a better life, leaving behind your family. I'm looking for a word with the meaning *a* *foreign* *country* *you* *voluntarily* [to exclude *exile*] *live* *in*

> I've been living in [expatriation] for five years.

My understanding is that in this sentence, *expatriation* referes to a *state* rather than a physical *place*.

> I hope my husband will return from [expatriation] soon.

I'm not sure this last sentence is correct with *expatriation* refering to a foreign country (place). What I'm particulary interested in is the phrase *return* *from* *Y*.

So, does expatriation work? any other word? Other words that I have a confused understanding of are exile, alienation and diaspora.

Comment: Consider "**abroad**" - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abroad. E.g.: "Studying abroad", "working abroad", "living abroad", "returning from abroad".

Comment: **Conquest** and **encroachment** can be used as nouns (as well as verbs), e.g. "Immigrants flooded the United States over decades with student and work visas, indoctrinating the locals and living in their conquest thereafter."

Comment: expatriot comes from the latin *ex patria*, which means away from your fatherland. expatriation is used about the process not the state, or the country you live in.

Comment: Any reason nobody yet has suggested _domicile_?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Abroad](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abroad) is the word you are looking for.

> In or to a foreign country; away from your home.

It is widely used in expressions like:

> I decided to **study abroad** for 2 years because it costs less money.
>
> I enjoy **living and working abroad** because I meet new kinds of people every day!
>
> I can't wait for my husband to **return from** his military operation **abroad**.

It also obviously works in both your example sentences, as per my previous examples (if you remove "in").

> I've been living abroad for five years.
>
> I hope my husband returns from abroad soon.

Update: Note that "abroad" is mostly used as an adverb, but can also be used as a [noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abroad), in expressions like "from abroad" as per my third example sentence and the OP's second example sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question: Isn't _abroad_ an adveb? If so, then how come we say **return** **from** **abroad**? Shouldn't it be return from (a place/a noun), or return from _being_ (or _living_) abroad?

Comment: @William It is not a stupid question. It is true that it is mostly an adverb. But it is sometimes, however rarely, used as a noun (meaning countries or lands abroad), a **mass noun** (which is the case in your second example - http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abroad) or even a preposition. "Return from abroad" returns a huge amount of hits on Google.

Comment: There are some examples of "abroad" usage in [a news story about how migrant workers send money home to their families](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2271455/Revealed-How-immigrants-America-sending-120-BILLION-struggling-families-home.html) _As a result, it has asked all Rwandans **living abroad** to contribute to a new 'solidarity fund' to make up the difference._

Comment: @William: Technically, I think *abroad* is an intransitive preposition (meaning a single word that functions as a prepositional phrase). *From* happily takes prepositional phrases as arguments, as in the famous "The call is coming **from inside the house**!"

Answer (score 7):

In formal contexts (e.g. immigration forms and other official documents), you can use the noun phrase *country of residence*.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to your new country as "adopted home" as the headline in [this article](http://www.guelphmercury.com/community-story/6822927-refugee-youth-explore-adopted-home-through-photography/) suggests:

> Refugee youth explore **adopted home** through photography

Answer (score 2):

As there is always more than one way to express a thought in English (with subtly different connotations), consider also the word [***sojournment***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sojournment):

*•temporary residence, as of a stranger or traveller*

Ex:

- "I've been living in *sojournment* for five years."
- "I hope my husband will return from *sojournment* soon."

Use of *sojournment* is more formal than, for instance, *abroad*, but carries the connotation of being a more business related than tourist related experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is a single verb which can be used instead of *return from Y* in your example, [*repatriate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/repatriate?s=t):

> to return to one's own country

So this would work:

> I hope my husband will *repatriate* soon.

Comment: But according to Merriam Webster, repatriate can only be used transitively. That is, you repatriate someone, but not someone repatriates.

Comment: @William right; I found & cited another dictionary which lists it as both transitive and intransitive.

Comment: @William, it can be intransitive. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repatriate